# Gap between border and page edge

Tags: css, border

I have added a border around my page which should stay fixed even when the page scrolls.
How do I remove the small gap between the red border and the edge of page??

```css
body::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 15px solid red;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor, purus non hendrerit bibendum, mauris nisi maximus metus, sit amet commodo augue purus quis lorem. Nullam laoreet nibh nisi, eu suscipit libero varius id. Nunc lobortis odio eu tempor vulputate. Sed placerat nisi gravida lorem laoreet congue. Nam blandit faucibus molestie. Sed tempus mi a arcu eleifend, ut malesuada elit ultricies. Sed odio leo, tempus non accumsan nec, condimentum viverra arcu. Nullam accumsan, elit sed vulputate ultricies, elit lorem interdum lectus, ut feugiat ipsum diam sed nulla. Etiam et pharetra turpis. Duis accumsan quam sit amet interdum blandit. Sed auctor hendrerit mauris ac vestibulum. Nam at dapibus lacus, non mattis turpis. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque vel condimentum enim, quis tincidunt purus. Fusce cursus odio non venenatis dictum. Maecenas felis felis, blandit a dictum ut, blandit sed justo.

Vestibulum placerat placerat elit eget auctor. Suspendisse auctor massa eros, a lobortis leo faucibus a. Pellentesque mi nibh, efficitur vitae dignissim quis, egestas luctus ante. Maecenas at blandit tellus. Sed eleifend, erat commodo sollicitudin egestas, nisl ante sollicitudin sem, eu venenatis nisi mauris at orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus nulla augue, dapibus et sem ac, vestibulum ultricies risus. Donec ut lectus risus. Mauris tincidunt, ipsum quis rhoncus scelerisque, quam augue molestie eros, dapibus gravida neque diam in quam. Sed vulputate ante ut tortor rhoncus maximus. Curabitur id facilisis leo, ac suscipit orci. Fusce auctor neque quis fringilla pretium.

Cras nec eros id est ullamcorper consequat. Quisque pellentesque venenatis pretium. Sed a ullamcorper massa. Morbi eget rutrum nisl. Nullam semper tellus ut purus lacinia ornare. Quisque sagittis auctor erat, sed volutpat turpis. Suspendisse vehicula faucibus lectus, nec iaculis turpis mattis ut. Aliquam dapibus felis lectus, sit amet mattis nunc ullamcorper quis. Nam dictum nibh ac pretium vehicula. Cras porta in neque nec convallis. Cras libero tellus, luctus id velit vel, molestie egestas nunc. Morbi vitae dolor metus. Donec vitae interdum sem, vitae condimentum ante. Cras in turpis et nisl tincidunt vehicula.

Sed ut magna commodo, iaculis velit vel, cursus velit. Curabitur nunc sem, maximus et ullamcorper in, venenatis vel sapien. Praesent vulputate, purus sit amet rhoncus lacinia, urna lectus venenatis dui, in elementum velit quam nec urna. Curabitur quis efficitur sem. Proin id feugiat mi. Duis sed diam vitae tortor mollis auctor vitae non erat. Aenean pulvinar accumsan luctus. Fusce at massa suscipit, gravida risus ut, laoreet tortor. Praesent vitae purus elit. Praesent feugiat augue eu tellus scelerisque, vel fringilla ligula suscipit.

Nulla ac elementum neque. Integer tincidunt sollicitudin cursus. Proin a lacus augue. Etiam scelerisque scelerisque commodo. Nulla eros felis, aliquet at tincidunt in, vulputate sit amet libero. Mauris sed vulputate urna, ac consectetur lacus. Duis eget lorem blandit, laoreet velit in, sagittis augue. Vestibulum ut erat quis ipsum aliquam fermentum. Ut varius odio lacus, ut dictum dolor laoreet non. Donec feugiat dictum magna, mollis mattis nibh bibendum quis. Sed ornare risus vel massa tristique, vel iaculis enim aliquet. Sed mauris erat, faucibus sit amet hendrerit eget, suscipit sed neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
```

Comment: The space is due to 'left:10px' and  'right:10px'. You should set both of them to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work fine !!

body::before {

```
content: '';
position: fixed;
top: 0vh;
left: 0vw;
right: 0vw;
bottom:0vh;
border: 15px solid red;
```

}

Comment: Haha! Sometimes things only work when others do it. Thanks for your help bud.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your css, the browser, by default adds some margin and padding to every container

```
* {margin: 0!important; padding:0!important;}
```

then you will have to add margins and paddings you need them

Comment: **Warning**: I would not recommend resetting every margin and padding, especially with !important, which should be avoided and only rarely be used. With the above code you get into CSS specificity troubles from the beginning. Keep you core CSS as clean as possible. :) https://cssspecificity.com/